# browser is not launched by Jenkins when executing cypress specs in headed mode

Tags: jenkins, cross-browser, cypress, mode

I configured a step in Jenkins to execute cypress specs in headed mode (the same command I can use on windows command prompt)

```
.\node_modules\.bin\cypress run --headed --browser edge --env NO_COLOR=1
```

I would expect Jenkins to launch the browser and execute the tests in headed mode (I use Jenkins locally on my laptop), but this is not happening (it's like cypress tests are executed in headless mode).

How can I perform cross-browser testing in a continuous integration fashion with Jenkins and cypress?

[image: local installation of jenkins]

Comment: Just a wild guess, but are you using jenkins docker container perhaps?

Comment: no, just Jenkins, locally, without container. Thanks Zaista